# Should Timezones be stored as a string or an integer offset?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, timezone

For storing a user's timezone in a database for a Rails app, would it be better to store the numerical offset (i.e. -8) or the name (Pacific Time (US & Canada))?

Storing the name allows for the application to deal with DST better, but what if in the future Rails is updated and has different names for the timezones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the timezone name. Don't worry about the timezone names changing. They don't change. There appears to be a strong commitment from the folks you maintain the [timezone database](http://www.iana.org/time-zones) to preserve backward compatibility names if they ever do. For example, new names like `America/New_York` were added along the way but the "old" names like `US/Eastern` still work. Additionally, the timezone definitions support timezones where the rules were different at different times, so even if the rules in one time zone are updated, local time for dates in the past should remain unchanged (unless the rules were changed to correct a mistake in the definition).

Storing the numerical offset is appropriate in conjunction with storing a specific time stamp, because it allows easy and unambiguous conversion to and from UTC, and the value of the offset at different dates in the same timezone is irrelevant.